Agregar una class a codigo en Wordpress
Estoy usando el tema Prime de WordPress. Pero tengo un problema: Cuando subo fotos a mi Blog, todas se ven de distinto tamaño, por eso quiero agregarle a las fotos el siguiente CSS:
height: 180px;
max-width: 100%;
object-fit: cover;

Mirando el código PHP, he identificado el lugar donde deseo agregar una clase; pero probé de varias formas y no logro que modifique la foto. Es para darle estilo. Éste es el código de WordPress:
<?php if( is_archive() || is_home() ){ ?>
    <div class="article-wrapper">
<?php } ?>
    
    <?php if( is_archive() || is_home() ){ blog_prime_post_thumbnail(); } ?>

    <div class="article-details">
        
        <?php if( is_archive() ||  is_home() ) : ?>

            <header class="entry-header">

En concreto, esta línea es la que muestra el thumbnail:
<?php if( is_archive() || is_home() ){ blog_prime_post_thumbnail(); } ?>

Quitando esa línea, el thumbnail no se muestra. Poniendola, me genera el siguiente código HTML para la imagen:
<img width="750" height="500" src="https://sitio.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2024/09/imagen.jpg" class="attachment-medium_large size-medium_large wp-post-image" alt="Menú para celíacos" decoding="async" srcset="https://sitio.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2024/09/imagen.jpg 768w" sizes="(max-width: 750px) 100vw, 750px">



Intenté agregar una clase así, pero no funcionó:
<class="foto" ?php if( is_archive() || is_home() ){ blog_prime_post_thumbnail(); } ?>

¿Dónde puede colocar el class para que funcione?

Los comentarios han sido movidos al chat; por favor, no continuar la discusión aquí. Antes de publicar un comentario bajo este, por favor revisa los propósitos de los comentarios. Los comentarios que no pidan clarificaciones o sugieran mejoras normalmente deben ser publicados como una respuesta, en [meta], o en el [chat]. Los comentarios que continúen la discusión podrán ser eliminados.

Idealmente, deberías cambiar el código de la función blog_prime_post_thumbnail() para añadir una clase a la imagen que quieras. Pero como parece que no tienes acceso al mismo, una solución simple sería envolver el resultado de esa llamada con un <div> que tenga una clase que tu quieras:
<?php if( is_archive() || is_home() ){ ?>
<div class="nombre-de-clase-propia">
  <?php blog_prime_post_thumbnail(); ?>
</div>
<?php } ?>

Una vez hagas eso, el código generado por PHP será algo como esto:
<div class="nombre-de-clase-propia">
  ...
  <img width="750" height="500" src="https://sitio.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2024/09/imagen.jpg" class="attachment-medium_large size-medium_large wp-post-image" alt="Menú para celíacos" decoding="async" srcset="https://sitio.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2024/09/imagen.jpg 768w" sizes="(max-width: 750px) 100vw, 750px">
  ...
</div>

Si te fijas, la imagen ya tiene sus propias clases:
<img ... class="attachment-medium_large size-medium_large wp-post-image" ... >

Entonces en tu CSS, puedes seleccionar las imágenes usando la clase que acabas de añadir y una de las clases de la imagen. Algo como esto:
.nombre-de-clase-propia .attachment-medium_large {
  height: 180px;
  width: 100%; /* cambié max-width con width */
  object-fit: cover;
}


Álvaro, hice tal cual tú lo indicas, y al agregar los estilos sigue sin aceptar el  object-fit: cover; https://ibb.co/yhNSYvs

@GabrielaQuinteros estás dando el estilo al div contenedor y no a la imagen. Fíjate mi selector es .nombre-de-clase-propia .attachment-medium_large y el que muestras en la captura es .nombre-de-clase-propia

Funciono Álvaro, gracias por tu ayuda... al fin, me falto el .attachment-medium_large. Saludos, mil gracias a ti y a todos por el tiempo y la ayuda!
